# Can't get location on application startup

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to develop little application which at startup shows the name of current location in a toast or something. The code I wrote will show a Toast on the display with the location only is I send the coordinates manually from the Emulator Control View from Eclipse.

My question: Is there a way to force somehow this sending of coordinates at the startup, because I want that Toast when the application is loaded? And how can I do it? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String welcomeMsg;
    private String crtLocationName;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initLocationManager();
    }

    private void initLocationManager(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 5000, this);
    }


     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            try {
                crtLocationName = getLocationName(location);

                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), crtLocationName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                welcomeMsg = "Location cannot be determined";
                crtLocationName = "";
            }

//          locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Emulator doesn't have a GPS receiver, the method `onLocationChanged` will be only invoked when you give some new coordinates through DDMS.

On the real phone, it will not show a Toast instantly; it will wait before it locates the GPS satellite and receive a GPS fix, then it will show the Toast message.

Comment: Then on the phone, it will startup with the Toast message?